# To Give ID Number Automatically With T-SQL Command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to give an ID number automatically but it will be a letter in front of every number.

I wrote the command below but it didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE
persons
(
ID NVARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 'N' + IDENTITY(1,1),
name NVARCHAR(50),
surname NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

The first command is wrong, what change should I do?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea at all. There are many good reasons to use `INT` as an artificial `PK`. You should reconsider your table design.

Comment: Thanks for advice, the answer below is solving ID problem and design problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   PersonID AS 'P-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into your table

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `PersonID` will contain values like `P-00001`, `P-00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.